# Invoke function before express static middleware

Tags: node.js, express, apache, middleware, static-files

I have a express static middleware to serve file under a specific folder, and I want to run a function before this middleware.

I tried something like this:

```
app.use('/projects', ProjectsRoute.addView, express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/resources/projects')))
```

Custom middleware:

```
const addView = async (req, res, next) => {

    if (req.originalUrl.split('/')[3] === 'index.htm') {
        try {
            const folder = req.originalUrl.split('/')[2]
            const project = await models.projects.findOne({ where: { folder } })

            if (project) {
                await models.projects.increment({ views: 1 }, { where: { id: project.id } })
            } else {
                next('Project not found')
            }

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
            next(err)
        }
    }
    next()
}
```

On a local environment it works fine, the function "addView" runs before serving the files, but as soon as it is on production, this works differently.

I have read in the documentation that the files will be served first and only run the my middleware if no files are found.

[serve-static 's doc](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static#fallthrough)

And this is what is happening on production. The middleware is only invoked if the file is not found as some sort of fallback.

I only want to run this custom middleware when serving files from the folder projects, so I don't want to create a middleware for all routes.

Comment: I don't think what you're saying is correct. Your `addView` middleware will always be invoked first and it shouldn't matter whether it's in prod or dev. You might need validate your assumptions and do some more testing.

Comment: This code has no direct dependency on whether it's prod or dev.  You will need to debug what the differences in execution of these two middlewares are in your different environments.  For example, perhaps the path here `express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/resources/projects'))` is not correct in prod?  Or, perhaps the database is different?  Or perhaps your parsing to get `folder` is not correct in prod.  Add a whole bunch of `console.log()` statements to `addView()` so you can see exactly what it's doing in both environments and compare.

Comment: I understand and it seems kinda odd but in production the addView() function does not even run when the files are found. Only when the files is not found, is when the addView() is invoked. I think this might have something to do with apache config, but honestly im complete lost on what it might be

Comment: How do you know it doesn't run? I strongly suspect that it runs but you are assuming it doesn't because of some side-effect you're misunderstanding. You're not describing what side-effect you are observing so we know it runs but don't know what to tell you.

Comment: I tested by modifying my middleware to ONLY return a error like next('error') and nothing more. Doing this still loads the files. The side effect is it still loading files, even though i return a error in my middleware and nothing more. But if no files are found, it return the error from my middleware.
That why i think this has something to do with 
https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static#fallthrough

Answer (score 0):

I've manage to get a workaround for this issue.

Instead of declaring the custom middleware joined with the express static middleware:

```
app.use('/projects', ProjectsRoute.addView, express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/resources/projects')))
```

I have separated the 2 like so:

```
app.use('/project', ProjectsRoute.addView)
app.use('/project', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/resources/projects')))
```

This seems to be working fine, since both gonna get called but that's the point.